# Updating Records Via Dynamic Form Variables

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form that allows the user to choose 4 records out of the whole set to appear in a specific order (1 through 4). The fields are dynamically named blah1, blah2, etc. However, the update queries are not working, and they're all defaulting to the value of 1 when I output the results.

```
<cfquery name="allRecipes" datasource="#request.db#">
    SELECT id, name, homepage_order
    FROM tblrecipes
    ORDER BY name
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getOnlySelected" dbtype="query">
    SELECT *
    FROM allRecipes
    WHERE homepage_order > 0
    ORDER BY homepage_order
</cfquery>

<cfloop from="1" to="4" index="i">
            <li>
                Position <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>: Current recipe published: <strong><cfoutput>#getOnlySelected['name']["#i#"]#</cfoutput></strong><br />
                Choose New:
                <cfselect name="position#i#" query="allRecipes" value="id" display="name" queryPosition="below" selected="#getOnlySelected['id']['#i#']#">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>  
                </cfselect>
            </li>

        </cfloop>
```

And the form submission queries:

```
<cfquery datasource="#request.db#">
        UPDATE tblrecipes
        SET homepage_order = 0
        WHERE 1=1
    </cfquery> //This query resets all the order values

    <cfif IsNumeric(form.position1)>
        <cfquery name="updateOrder1" datasource="#request.db#">
            UPDATE tblrecipes
            SET homepage_order = 1
            WHERE id = #form.position1#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>

    <cfif IsNumeric(form.position2)>
        <cfquery name="updateOrder2" datasource="#request.db#">
            UPDATE tblrecipes
            SET homepage_order = 2
            WHERE id = #form.position2#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>

    <cfif IsNumeric(form.position3)>
        <cfquery name="updateOrder3" datasource="#request.db#">
            UPDATE tblrecipes
            SET homepage_order = 3
            WHERE id = #form.position3#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>

    <cfif IsNumeric(form.position4)>
        <cfquery name="updateOrder4" datasource="#request.db#">
            UPDATE tblrecipes
            SET homepage_order = 4
            WHERE id = #form.position4#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
```

Here is an example dump of the form data. The values for each position are correct.

```
FIELDNAMES  POSITION1,POSITION2,POSITION3,POSITION4,SUBMIT
POSITION1   81
POSITION2   82
POSITION3   80
POSITION4   78
SUBMIT  Update Order
```

The query result looks the same, before and after the form submission

```
HOMEPAGE_ORDER  ID  NAME
1   81  Okonomiyaki
1   82  Apple Chutney Cubes
1   80  Asparagus for the Family
1   78  Coconut Curry Sauce Cubes
CACHED  false
EXECUTIONTIME   0
SQL     SELECT * FROM allRecipes WHERE homepage_order > 0 ORDER BY homepage_order
```

Comment: **Use [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) in your queries!**

Comment: +100 for the cfqueryparam!  Never put user-submitted data directly into a query without cleansing it in some way (which is part of what cfqueryparam does).  It's just asking for a sql injection attack.

Comment: You are correct, and I usually do. </cflazy>

Comment: Can you dump a sample of `tblrecipes` before and after your updates? Specifically showing the homepage_order of those 4 ids above ie (81,82,80 and 78)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

1. on the page which is being submitted to. Just to confirm whether it's the form values being sent or the code server-side which is the problem
2. Similarly, add something to output whether the updates in your update code are being run. You say they're all defaulting to 1, which makes me think that the code is running though.
3. Download and install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and use that to watch what values the browser is sending through.
4. Read the source of the page with the form in it. Are there actually tags around the right bit of the form so it's submitting the data you expect?

From the look of your code, the only way the update queries could be setting all four values to 1 is if thats' what the client is sending, so I'd suspect something in the generated page, although I've just re-created the bones of your example locally and can't see anything immediately wrong with it.

Comment: Add a cfdump var="#FORM#" to the processing page to see exactly what the incoming data is.  My instinct was also to confirm that the form being built is exactly what you expect, so take a look at the HTML source generated on the front-end.

Comment: I updated the post with this information. However, I cannot dump the update queries, saying they are undefined (yet each of them are named accordingly).

Comment: I'd put <cflog> or <cfoutput> statements inside each of the <cfif statements you have. If the queries are undefined, then it would imply that the queries aren't running. Also, with CF debug turned on, what queries does CF say its run? This is looking quite baffling now!

Comment: @AngrySpartan - `UPDATE` queries do not return a resultset. You need to use the `result` attribute instead. Also, I tested your code. It successfully updates the selected records. So I think something else is going on .. Can you post a before and after data sample?

Comment: @Leigh, what is this result attribute, and the tag it goes with?  I updated the post with the query results as well.

Comment: Result is an attribute for [cfquery](http://cfdocs.org/cfquery) - it returns information about the query (rather than the query resultset you get with the name attribute).